# Drying sodium tetraborate for use as a standard

Tags: titration, purification, recrystallization

I am currently attempting to purify technical grade sodium tetraborate decahydrate by recrystallization for use as a titration standard. I don't have a requirement for a specific grade or purity. I'm just looking to improve my results a bit.

I understand that one of its qualities for use as a primary standard is the stable hydration number. However, if I'm drying wet crystals, what would be the best way to ensure that there is no extra water without affecting this? Could heating produce the pentahydrate or anhydrous form?

This is a separate question really, but would it be better to convert to boric acid, recrystallise and then neutralise with a sodium base?

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to consider salts with crystal water as standards. As, with possibly rate exceptions, you cannot guarantee sufficient moisture elimination and defined composition at the same time.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Yes, they would need to be dry, but not anhydrous. Sodium tetraborate decahydrate is considered a good primary standard. Is this dried in some way not accessible to a lab? Or purified in some way that doesn't involve water?

Comment: I suppose borax may be within those exceptions. But the result should be controlled by a commercial primary standard. BTW it is not true decahydrate, as there are 4 OH groups bound to boron.

Comment: Yes, I could just buy a higher purity commercial primary standard, but I'm interested to find out how much closer to that I can get with the supplies I have and basic methods and equipment. The question is what drying method to use. Would there, for instance, be a temperature to stay below to avoid driving of the water of crystallisation?

Comment: Unless some differential gravimetry data are available, you may need to experiment to get m=f(T).

Comment: Do you mean that comparing to a mass/temperature curve could indicate when the sample has dried, or something like that, thermogravimetry?

Comment: Whatever your instrumentation allows. There are 2 constraints: T high enough to dry it well T low enough not causing releasing crystal water. I would use known masses from the same lot, dried at different temperatures, plot the chart and decide. Or search for online date before that.

Comment: recrystallise below 50C to ensure the decahydrate forms, don't heat it to dry it.

Comment: Probably also aim to obtain small and equally sized crystals, and spread them out in a thin layer - or use a rotary evaporator to constantly agitate, with a heating bath and not much vacuum (or a gentle air flow).